# bubble sort in python sorting to a new array

Tags: arrays, bubble-sort

I wrote a bubble sort algorithm and i want to sort elements to a new array. But i'm not sure where to put the append function so the sorted values appear in my new array b.

```
a = [1,6,8,5,3]
b = []
n = len(a)
for i in range(n-1):
   for j in range(0, n-i-1):
       if a[j] < a[j + 1]:
          a[j], a[j + 1] = a[j + 1], a[j]

print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append sorted values to new array using below example

for i in range(n):
b.append(a[i])

Comment: i get values [1,6,3,6,8] instead of [8,6,5,3,1]

Comment: @Sofie add b.sort(reverse=True)

Comment: I am writing a sorting algoritm lol

Comment: sorry my bad :-)

Comment: a = [1,6,8,5,3]
b = []
n = len(a)
for i in range(n-1):
   for j in range(0, n-i-1):
       if a[j] < a[j + 1]:
          a[j], a[j + 1] = a[j + 1], a[j]

# append the sorted list to new array
for i in range(n):
    b.append(a[i])

print(b)

Comment: yep my goal is to get the numbers that were sorted in array a using a bubble sort tin a new array b. i can't wrap my head around where i should use append... Probably after this line a[j], a[j + 1] = a[j + 1], a[j]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249327/discussion-between-sofie-zippay-and-kgbonnet).